# Getting object into array

Tags: php

I'm not so advanced in PHP, just basic I can understand. I was trying an API and it returns it as object, how do I convert it to array? I did searched through stackoverflow and found lots of solution, but none works for me. **$array returns empty array.** Here is my code:-

```
while (1) {

    $line = '';
    $w->pollMessage();
    $msgs = $w->getMessages();
    foreach ($msgs as $m) {

        print_r($msgs);
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($msgs), true);
        print_r($array);
}
```

And here is the result I get print_r($msgs):

```
Array
(
    [0] => ProtocolNode Object
        (
            [tag:ProtocolNode:private] => message
            [attributeHash:ProtocolNode:private] => Array
                (
                    [from] => amy
                    [type] => text
                    [id] => 3EB0E191F15B831D244E
                    [t] => 1462939886
                    [notify] => Nick
                )

            [children:ProtocolNode:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ProtocolNode Object
                        (
                            [tag:ProtocolNode:private] => enc
                            [attributeHash:ProtocolNode:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [v] => 2
                                    [type] => msg
                                )

                            [children:ProtocolNode:private] =>
                            [data:ProtocolNode:private] => 3

                        )

                    [1] => ProtocolNode Object
                        (
                            [tag:ProtocolNode:private] => body
                            [attributeHash:ProtocolNode:private] =>
                            [children:ProtocolNode:private] =>
                            [data:ProtocolNode:private] => good
                        )

                )

            [data:ProtocolNode:private] =>
        )

)
```

Comment: why `while (1)`???? and what you want?

Comment: @FrayneKonok
I have to use while (1) because to receive input from user, I need the object to be converted into array.

Comment: `print_r($array);` is an associative array...

Comment: @FrayneKonok I written there it returns an empty array. Do you need me to bold it for you?

Comment: You need to mention that your `$array` did't show anything. just `It returns empty array` is not enough to understand that your `$array` variable goes empty.

Comment: Your input to `json_decode` is **not** JSON format.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I tried other method too, it doesn't work either

Comment: @RyanVincent I just need to get from and id

Comment: Can you define the `$w` variable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem. You already have an array and do not need to handle with json. If you don't like it as array, you can simply cast it to an object.

```
$myArray = (object) $myArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

Requirements: Walk a multiway object tree and apply a `callback` to each node.

[Working demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/568492)

Explanation:

1) There are a lot of private properties and I am not sure 'casting to an array' will let get at them.

2) If you have the original class then you may want to usesome of the methods on it.

The approach I used is:

a) Provide a 'tree walk' that will visit all the nodes in the tree. I am not concerned about order of visiting. Just to visit then all.

b) Rather than provide specific code to process the node. I provide a 'callback' hook.

c) As I don't have  the class I create a simple one that will give me easy access to the private properties.

#### The Tree Walk function:

```
 function walkProtocolNodes(\ProtocolNode $currentNode, /* callable */ $processNode)
 {
     $processNode($currentNode); 

     foreach ($currentNode->children as $nextNode) {
         walkProtocolNodes($nextNode, $processNode);
     }
     return;
 }
```

#### Sample `processNode` function:

All it does is append the `attributesHash` to the output array (`outputResults`)...

```
 $processNode = function (\ProtocolNode $node) use (&$outputResults) {
     $outputResults[] = $node->attributeHash;
 };
```

#### Run the `tree walk`:

```
walkProtocolNodes($node1, $processNode);
```

#### The 'protocolNode' class I used:

```
class ProtocolNode {

    private $tag = 'message';
    private $attributeHash = array();
    private $children = array();
    private $data = 'good';

    public function __construct($attrs = array()) {
        $this->attributeHash = $attrs;
    }

    public function addChild(\ProtocolNode $node) {
        $this->children[] = $node;
    }

    public function __get($propertyName) {
        return $this->$propertyName;
    }
}
```

See the `demonstration` to see the output